# NiFi : Prepend (orAppend) a line number to all records in a flowfile

Tags: apache-nifi

I am using NiFi 1.9.2

I am reading a text file which happens to be a csv file. I have the Contents of the file in the Contents of a flowFile.

Contents are

```
a,b,c
d,e,f
g,h,i
```

I want to prepend a line number to all records in the flowfile and get

```
1,a,b,c
2,d,e,f
3,g,h,i
```

each time I feed a file through this processor

I can achieve something close by using the ReplaceText processor with Properties as follows:

```
Search Value : (?m)(^.*$)
Replacement Value : ${nextInt()},$1
```

But because nextInt() persists it's value over the lifetime of the running NiFi instance I get

```
    0,a,b,c
    1,d,e,f
    2,g,h,i
for 1st execution

    3,a,b,c
    4,d,e,f
    5,g,h,i
for the next execution etc
```

Additionally, from the NiFi expression-language-guide, the "counter is shared across all NiFi components, so calling this function multiple times from one Processor will not guarantee sequential values within the context of a particular Processor."

1. Is there a way to ensure the line numbers always start at 0 for each execution of this processor for the lifetime of the NiFi instance, and are always sequential?
2. What the range of the counter?
3. Can I get the counter to start at 1?

Comment: You can try - `ExecuteScript` or `UpdateAttribute` to maintain a local state for counter variable, refer to this - https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-update-attribute-nar/1.14.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.attributes.UpdateAttribute/additionalDetails.html

Comment: Thanks @VikramsinhShinde. These processors are very useful for performing an operation on a flowFile-by-flowFile basis. I want to perform an operation on individual records in a flowFile.  I can write a custom processor to this in Java quite easily, but first choice is to try a out-of-the-box NiFi solution.

Comment: I have written a custom script to implement exactly this use case. I haven't come across any other solution.

Comment: Thanks @Mallik.  I did the same - wrote a custom processor in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the content to several lines then use fragment.index to prepent the counter to the lines. After that you can merge them again.

The Flow:
[image]

GenerateFlowFile:
[image]

SplitText:
[image]

ReplaceText:
[image]

MergeContent:
[image]
Don't forget to add a new line (Shift+Enter) to Demarcator attribute.

Result:
[image]

You can use `${Fragment.index:minus(1)}` if you want to count from zero.

Comment: Thank you @Behrouz. That's pretty smart. In SplitText I had to change the 'Remove Trailing Newlines' to false in order to get the merged output to create each record on a new line.  Question : SplitText creates a new flowFile for each record of the input file. MergeContent recombines them.  From the tests I ran it appears that the original order of records is preserved. But is this guaranteed?

Comment: @mikec As I know the order of records will be guaranteed to preserve. 
In MergeContent, "fragment.index" attribute indicates the order in which the fragments should be assembled.

Comment: @mikec I had added new line for each line in "Demarcator" attribute of MergeContent.